# How do I Escape @ in Blazor Component HTML Attributes?

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to use `<InputText />` to render the following:

```html
<input placeholder="@Handle" class="valid">
```

Here is what I tried:

```html
<InputText @bind-Value="Handle" placeholder="Handle" />    @* <- Compiles, but not what I want. *@
<InputText @bind-Value="Handle" placeholder="@@Handle" />  @* <- Fails. *@
```

But I get the following error:

```
RAZORGENERATE : error RZ9986: Component attributes do not support complex content (mixed C# and markup). 
Attribute: 'placeholder', text: '"@"Handle'
```

So using `@@` is technically still razor code (an escaped '@') and can't be used with an attribute. How can I put render an '@' in an HTML attribute?

I am using .NET 5.0, server-side Blazor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### HTML Solution

Immediately realized I could just use HTML character codes. This works:

```html
<InputText @bind-Value="@Inputs.Handle" placeholder="&#64;Handle" />
```

#### Razor Solution

Or, I could just use razor and do this:

```html
<InputText @bind-Value="@Inputs.Handle" placeholder="@($"@{UserHandle}")" />
```

---

The moral is, **you can't combine razor with raw HTML in component attributes** (and know that `@@` is still razor syntax). Pick **one** and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add another possibility
You could add something like

```cs
@code{
    private const string placeholder = "@Handle";
}
```

And then

```
<InputText @bind-Value="@Inputs.Handle" placeholder="@placeholder" />
```

But this can quickly become very large and doesn't answer the question "How to escape @ in razor components". Maybe ask Microsoft?

Comment: [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#razor-syntax) states "To escape an ```@``` symbol in Razor markup, use a second ```@``` symbol"

Comment: @DouglasRiddle Miscrosoft is overusing the word "Razor". There are Razor Views, Razor Pages and Razor Components, which are quite different things. The whole point of this question is that it seems that the trick that works in .cshtml files doesn't work in .razor file, or at least in component attributes.